# Scala cat library validation-Collect all invalid objects

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats

I am a newbie to scala. Is it possible to collect a list of all invalid objects after validation?
For ex: There are a list of order objects.After validation some are valid and some are invalid.

Somebody body with knowledge in cat library please give me an insight into this.

Comment: You want to use [**Validated**](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/validated.html). Something like: `rawData.traverse(validateFun)`

Comment: "after validation" you say. So if you have a `List[Validated[?,?]]` then you can partition it: `val (vld,invld) = validatedDataList.partition(_.isValid)`

Answer (score 0):

Given a list of `Validated[E, A]`, you can split them into a list of `E` and a list of `A` using [`partitionBifold`](https://typelevel.org/cats/api/cats/Foldable.html#partitionBifold%5BH%5B_,_%5D,A,B,C%5D(fa:F%5BA%5D)(f:A=%3EH%5BB,C%5D)(implicitA:cats.Alternative%5BF%5D,implicitH:cats.Bifoldable%5BH%5D):(F%5BB%5D,F%5BC%5D)):

```scala
import cats._, cats.data._ cats.implicits._

val validations:  List[Validated[String, Int]] =
    List(1.valid, "Err".invalid, 2.valid, "Also Err".invalid)

validations.partitionBifold(identity)
// == (List("Err", "Also Err"), List(1, 2))
```

This works for any `Foldable` instead of List, and any element type for which there is a [`Bifoldable`](https://typelevel.org/cats/api/cats/Bifoldable.html) instance, e.g `Either` or a tuple.